# Unable to launch internet explorer ---Selenium

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I am just checking to launch IE11 via selenium Webdriver.
Very strange I get this run time exception.Please help.
Internetexplorer driver is there in the path mentioned and selenium-server standalone  is there in the build path.
I have a code like this:

```
 import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
 import org.openqa.selenium.ie.InternetExplorerDriver;
 import org.openqa.selenium.By;
 import org.openqa.selenium.JavascriptExecutor;
 import org.openqa.selenium.NoSuchElementException;
 import org.openqa.selenium.Platform;

 import org.openqa.selenium.WebElement;

 import org.openqa.selenium.remote.DesiredCapabilities;
 import org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver;

  public class Test {
    static String url="https://meapps-stg70.aa.com/tessmapsui/" ;
     public static void main(String[] args) {

      System.setProperty("webdriver.ie.driver", "C:\\Users\\Public\\IEDriverServer.exe");
       WebDriver driver = new InternetExplorerDriver();
       driver.get("https://xx.com/xxui/");
       driver.findElement(By.id("userID")).sendKeys("xxxxx");
       driver.findElement(By.id("password")).sendKeys("xxxxx");
       driver.findElement(By.id("login")).click();
       driver.findElement(By.id("qs_aircft")).sendKeys("XYZ");;
       driver.findElement(By.name("twdReport_Submit")).click();


       }
       }

   It gives the runtime exception as follows:
            Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoSuchMethodError:           com.google.common.base.Preconditions.checkArgument(ZLjava/lang/String;I)V
at org.openqa.selenium.remote.service.DriverService$Builder.usingPort(DriverService.java:285)
at org.openqa.selenium.ie.InternetExplorerDriver.setupService(InternetExplorerDriver.java:242)
at org.openqa.selenium.ie.InternetExplorerDriver.<init>(InternetExplorerDriver.java:211)
at org.openqa.selenium.ie.InternetExplorerDriver.<init>(InternetExplorerDriver.java:150)
at Test.main(Test.java:44)
```

Answer (score 0):

Working fine now.Updated to latest Gauva libraries and removed the older ones.clean and rebuild and run.